# Flutter: how to fit widget with aspect ratio inside its parent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app, aspect-ratio

I want have two widgets center in a container.

Widget A with aspect ratio 1:1 and fitting in container.

Widget B is a Text with its height fitting is content and its width filling parent.

For example:

In portrait mode

[image]

In landscape mode

[image]

Here is the code that I tried:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                  ),
                )),
            Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(child: Text("TEST", textAlign: TextAlign.center)))
          ],
        ));
  }
```

But result is like this:

In portrait mode

[image]

In landscape mode

[image]

Widget A is filling all spaces in portrait mode instead of fitting inside.

How to make Widget A fitting in container?

Comment: *"how to fit widget with aspect ratio inside its parent?"* - see `FittedBox`

Comment: @pskink How does a single FittedBox do all the center, fitting, and aspect ratio works?

Comment: do you want to know all the details? if so, check `RenderFittedBox` [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart#L2391) file

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes. You can try this. Maybe this is not the right and efficient way. But you can try it.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //Calculate width and height as your wish
    double width = size.width < size.height ? size.width : size.height * .5;
    double height = width * 1.1;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              child:
                  Container(width: width, height: height, color: Colors.yellow),
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(child: Text("TEST", textAlign: TextAlign.center)))
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Based on the orientation, we change the parent widget of the main yellow box and text column.

I placed yellow box within an Align widget as it constraints the size, then placed it inside the AspectRatio widget to maintain the desired ratio.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: OrientationBuilder(
    builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (orientation.name == "portrait") {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Text("Text"),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text("Text"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
          ],
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```